# (Share Intent) External Share Not Working in Android 12

Tags: java, android, share

After Android 12 update share intent not working in Samsung S10 device.This code is properly working in below Android version 12 devices but could not find the reason why in
android 12 is filtering out.

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        // (Optional) If you want a preview title, set it with Intent.EXTRA_TITLE
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, str_title);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.cyranolab.media/msg/?q=507dddd6-8e43-11ec-9d11-061d7e6be791");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, str_title);

        Intent receiver = new Intent(getActivityContext, UserSelectedShareBroadcast.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivityContext,
                    0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivityContext,
                    0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }

        Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Choose", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent externalEmailIntent = new Intent(getActivityContext, ExternalEmailShareActivity.class);
        externalEmailIntent.putExtra("programId", programId);
        externalEmailIntent.putExtra("sharedResourceId", sharedResourceId);
        externalEmailIntent.putExtra("INBOX", "Inbox");
        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(externalEmailIntent, "Package Name", "Email to", R.drawable.ic_mail_outline));
        // convert intentList to array
        LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[0]);

        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
        int REQUEST_SHARED_URL = 2;
        getActivityContext.startActivityForResult(openInChooser, REQUEST_SHARED_URL);
    }
```

I want to share my Programs to other Apps. I unable to share my program to other apps. Share intent not opened, After android 12 update.

Comment: That is not enough code. We can not see what you do

Comment: `sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedURL);` The url should be in EXTRA_STREAM. Further we still dont know what you do as we do not see what kind of url you have. You should also elaborate on 'not working' as we have no idea what that means.

Comment: This url was i shared. https://www.cyranolab.media/msg/?q=507dddd6-8e43-11ec-9d11-061d7e6be791

Comment: I tried with EXTRA_STREAM but still i facing this issue.

Comment: Put the used url in your post as code (not in a comment) and adapt your code so we see that you use EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: `@SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag") PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivityContext, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` Android 12 wants the `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `FLAG_MUTABLE` but you are suppressing the warning.

Comment: @Per.J Thank you for your comment i aaded the flag FLAG_IMMUTABLE and FLAG_MUTABLE flag. Now open the share intent but the content was in returned null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing FLAG_IMMUTABLE
To declare that a given PendingIntent object is mutable or immutable, use the PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE flag, respectively. Above code Just i added this lines: Working fine now

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivityContext,
                    0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivityContext,
                    0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```